# pip installed google.colab on local jupyter and getting os error

Tags: google-colaboratory, oserror

I use google colab, and so I think of using google colab packages in my local jupyter environment and so install google.colab in my local jupyter.
After that, it starts showing me os error, and so I remove python 2-3 times and delete all libraries and install all things from fresh.

After that, I start getting this error

**OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application** when I use pandas library or any other library in my jupyter notebook. I'm struck over this for the last 5-6 months, and I appreciate all your suggestions.

---

I use this code in my notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.io.stata.read_stata('TRADHIST_WP.dta')
data=data.to_csv('my_stata_file.csv')
```

and get this error

---

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7e43326a167f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 data = pd.io.stata.read_stata('TRADHIST_WP.dta')
      3 data_csv=data.to_csv('my_stata_file.csv')

~\opencv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
      9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     10     try:
---> 11         __import__(dependency)
     12     except ImportError as e:
     13         missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")

~\opencv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138 
    139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
    142     from . import core

~\opencv\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    346 
    347         if handle is None:
--> 348             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    349         else:
    350             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```